# How to update ruby version ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, rvm

When I update the version of ruby 2.2.3 to 2.3.1. it returns the error displayed below.

```
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/i386/ruby-2.3.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `rvm help mount`?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [rbenv](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Use the link for installation steps. Its very simple and easy to use as compared to RVM.

I have installed Ruby 2.3.1 successfully on my Ubuntu 14.4.

Comment: While I may agree, that does not answer his specific question.